# How can you represent mathematical constant "e" as a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, constants

How can you represent mathematical constant "e" as a value in JavaScript?

Comment: Could you explain your question a little bit futher? `Math.E` is a value of that constant, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's as easy as

```
Math.E
```

Answer (score 8):

Other ways include:

```
Math.exp(1)
```

Approximations:

`3-sqrt(5/63)`

or

```
(Math.PI^4 + Math.PI^5)^(1/6)
```

which are good to 7 digits

and

`163^(32/163)` which is good to 6 digits

Comment: +1 Approximations are good to know. The OP probably didn't know about Math.E, so he was probably looking for something along this line originally.

Answer (score 3):

Answer was too short, so here is a much much longer version.

`Math.E`

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Math.E` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the constant:

```
Math.E
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript provides many mathematical constants that can be accessed from the `Math object`.

The one you want is `Math.E`

Answer (score 0):

e is represented by Math.E. But if your intention is to compute e^x, don't write Math.E^x. Use Math.exp(x) instead. It wouldn't be the first time someone has asked for e when they really want exp.

Comment: Thank you, but I was actually looking for constant e, which is something like 2.7...  I completely see and understand the trap you reference.